# linux + from where uname -r take the linux version information

Tags: linux, kernel

when I type the uname -r command on linux:

```
uname -r
```

I get the following info:

```
2.6.18-274.7.1.el5PAE
```

my question from which file uname -r read this info , or from where uname -r read the Data ?

Comment: It comes from the running kernel.

Comment: It uses the uname system call. http://linux.die.net/man/2/uname

Comment: from uname -r I get "2.6.18-274.7.1.el5PAE" is it possible to change the info so by typing uname -r I will get different info as "2.6.24-274.7.1.el5PAE" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The files like following you can change:**

```
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld proc]$ ls -l /proc/sys/kernel/{hostname,domainname}
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 10 00:07 /proc/sys/kernel/domainname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 10 00:07 /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
```

**But files like following, you can't change values:**

```
[sgeorge@SUKU proc]$ ls -l /proc/sys/kernel/{osrelease,ostype,version}
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 10 00:07 /proc/sys/kernel/osrelease
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 10 00:07 /proc/sys/kernel/ostype
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 10 00:07 /proc/sys/kernel/version
```

**Demo:**

```
[root@sgeorge-ld ~]# sudo echo "SUKU" > /proc/sys/kernel/hostname

[root@sgeorge-ld ~]# bash

[root@SUKU ~]# echo 121212 > /proc/sys/kernel/version
bash: /proc/sys/kernel/version: Permission denied

[root@SUKU ~]# echo 121212 > /proc/sys/kernel/ostype
bash: /proc/sys/kernel/ostype: Permission denied

[root@SUKU ~]# echo 121212 > /proc/sys/kernel/osrelease
bash: /proc/sys/kernel/osrelease: Permission denied
```

You can't modify these values.

These files can be tuned only when you build a new kernel.